# Configure SocketServer to work with Django

Tags: python, django, socketserver

I have a device that communicates with TCP port. It came with an desktop application which only runs in windows. but I want to use it in a linux server and with a django app. I tried to communicate with `SocketServer` library and it works fine but i'm having problem using djangos ORM in socket server. I need to store the data to database.

Comment: Have you tried to run anything or any approach on `linux` with `django`? If yes, please put your code here.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an django app that was built for the data for devices. In the app I have a file named `socket_server.py`. The code of it is given below

`

```
import SocketServer
import django
from models import Demo

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
def handle(self):
    # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
    self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
    print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
    print self.data
    demo = Demo(
        text=self.data
    )
    demo.save()
    self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()`
```

and i got the following when I try to run the `socket_server.py` file 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket_server.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .models import Demo
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
niloy@niloy-PC ~/PycharmProjects/django-practice/books $ python socket_server.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket_server.py", line 5, in <module>
    from models import Demo
  File "/home/niloy/PycharmProjects/django-practice/books/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Publisher(models.Model):
  File "/home/niloy/PycharmProjects/django-practice/books/models.py", line 10, in Publisher
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1043, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
niloy@niloy-PC ~/PycharmProjects/django-practice/books $ python socket_server.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket_server.py", line 5, in <module>
    from models import Demo
  File "/home/niloy/PycharmProjects/django-practice/books/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Publisher(models.Model):
  File "/home/niloy/PycharmProjects/django-practice/books/models.py", line 10, in Publisher
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1043, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use standalone Django features, you should set up Django manually using `django.setup()` after importing it.
See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage).